# Redshift query not returning certain columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have encountered a strange error on on of our tables ("nav") with the following structure:

```
position  | character varying(400)
timestamp | timestamp without time zone
```

If I run the following query, I get back, as expected, all matching results for the 2 columns:

```
SELECT * FROM nav WHERE timestamp >= '2019-03-24' AND timestamp < '2019-03-25';
```

However, if I run the following query, I get back the same number of results, but each field/row is empty:

```
SELECT position FROM nav WHERE timestamp >= '2019-03-24' AND timestamp < '2019-03-25';
```

I run the same query on similar tables and experience no issues. Any ideas as to what may be causing the second to return blanks in the rows please?

Comment: Can you share sample data, and both outputs

Comment: This sounds to me like an issue with the tool you're using to query Redshift rather than an issue with Redshift itself. What tool are you using?

Comment: @NathanGriffiths I am using psql

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this using Aginity Workbench for Redshift, the above queries always return values (although I have no idea what your data looks like). Possibly this is an artifact of using psql with Redshift, I'm not sure. What happens if you run the following: `select "position" from nav` ?

Comment: Thanks @NathanGriffiths I tried it but same result unfortunately. Strange thing is we have another table that is very similar - same field types, names and values and for it the queries all run fine. It is just this one table.

Comment: Try adding the the schema name to the table reference.  I.e., schema.nav